# What is the rank of an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves

Is it the amount of rational points on the curve(That aren't integers)? So if an elliptic curve has a rank of 1, does that mean it has only 1 rational point on the curve?(In both X and Y)

I've been trying to search it up on google but it the explanations are so vague. I'd be grateful if somebody could explain to me what the rank of an elliptic curve is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rational points on an elliptic curve with rational coefficients
form an Abelian group. A theorem of Mordell proves that this
group is finitely generated. Thus it is isomorphic to $T\times\Bbb Z^r$
where $T$ is a finite group (the *torsion subgroup*) and $r$ is
a non-negative integer, the *rank*. So $r$ is positive iff the curve
has infinitely many rational points.

Comment: So if an elliptic curve has a rank of 0, does that mean it has limited rational points? Or none

Comment: Let me rewrite my last sentence: So $r$ is zero iff the curve has finitely many rational points.